# Depurar una aplicación en Android Studio sin pasar por clases ocultas

Tags: android, android-studio, depuración

Soy bastante nuevo usando Android Studio y resulta que me gustaría poder depurar las aplicaciones que hago pero cada vez que lo hago, muchas veces me salta a otras clases (parece que son ocultas). En este caso, estoy programando con libgdx (es una libreria para programar juegos) y tengo trozo de este código:

```
if (rect.overlaps(nave.rect) && nave.alive) {
        remove();
        Nave nave = new Nave();
        nave.vidas++;
}
```

He intentado depurar a partir de la última línea ya que al testear el juego en mi móvil, las vidas del objeto no son incrementadas. El problema lo tengo que después de pasar por esta línea, me salta a una clase llamada "Group.java" que no sé si debe ser una clase oculta o del propio IDE, pero sale un candado en el icono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta clase parece que tiene un montón de código y después se llama a otra clase oculta y a otra, total, que estoy todo el día presionando F8 para saltar de línea en línea y esto es un no terminar.

Lo que yo quiero, es que sólo me depure el código que yo he escrito, no que se me vaya a otras clases del sistema/ocultas o no sé lo que son (aunque sean utilizadas). Debo decir que esta no es la primera vez que me pasa, cuando hice aplicaciones más básicas también me pasaba y la verdad no sé cómo hacerlo para evitarlo.

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Ya que se me está dificultando y mucho para depurar una aplicación.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour].

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que estas usando F8?, esta tecla hace un step over(paso sobre) la linea y no penetra en las clases usadas, asegúrate que estas usando step over, ademas, en cualquier momento puedes usar Step out, para salir de la clase en la que profundizaste y volver a la principal.

Answer (score 0):

En Android Studio ve a File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Stepping y bajo el checkbox "Do not step into the classes" crea un nuevo patrón con el botón que tiene un sígno + y una interrogación. En la caja que aparece introduce `"android.*"` (sin comillas) y acepta. Repite con `"com.android.*"` y con aquellos espacios de nombre que quieras evitar.

Eso si, documenta esos cambios porque quizá más adelante si quieras depurar otras clases y no recuerdes que las tienes "ignoradas".